# How to configure Jackson deserializer for Retrofit2 responses via Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer class?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, retrofit2, jackson2

I am using Retrofit2 to call distant web services in a Spring Batch application, and for deserializing JSON responses I would like to configure a global Jackson deserializer via the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` class.
My configuration is:

- Spring Boot version 3.0.6
- Retrofit version 2.9.0
- Jackson version 2.13.5

I've already tried to define `ObjectMapper` configuration in a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` object and it works, but I still need to specify `.addConverter(JacksonConverterFactory.create(<builder>)` on each `RetrofitBuilder()` call:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyRestWSImpl {

    @Bean
    MyRestWS myRestWS (@Value("${url}") String url) {
        return new RetrofitBuilder()
            .url(url)
            .addConverter(JacksonConverterFactory.create(
                new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
                    .deserializers(new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(MY_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER))
                    .build()
            )
            .client()
            .configure()
            .build()
            .create(MyRestWS.class);
    }
}
```

I'm searching for a better option.
Is there a way in which I can achieve the same result by using the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` functional interface instead?

I tried to define a bean of type `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` as seen [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-customize-jackson-objectmapper), but it does not seem to be taken into account by Retrofit2, although the bean is created:

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
        return builder -> builder
            .deserializers(new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(MY_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER));
    }
}
```

Console:

```
DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'jsonCustomizer'
...
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "2023-05-26 17:04:52"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the customizer, you should inject a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` into your bean and use it to build the object mapper.

e.g.

```java
    @Bean
    SonarqubeClient sonarqubeClient(SonarqubeProperties sonarqubeProperties, Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = objectMapperBuilder.build();
```

Comment: After some tries, I came to the conclusion that your solution is the best I can get. I hoped it worked somehow without injecting anything explicitly, and without adding  .addConverter() to the RetrofitBuilder() call, but apparently that is not possible. I ended up injecting the auto-configured ObjectMapper however, instead of injecting the builder. Thank you!